# Python Hash Table implemented using lists

Tags: python, hash-map

I implemented a Python Hash Table using only lists.
Here is my implementation:

```
class HashTable:
    # Initialize the table with a fixed size of 54 slots
    def __init__(self):
        self.Table = [None] * 54

    def _get_value(self, key): #This is my hash function.
        # It finds the hash of every string. total % 54
        total = hash(key)
        return total % 54

    def insert(self, key):
        val = self._get_value(key)
        col = False #Collision bool
        index = 0

        if self.Table[val] == None: #Empty slot - turn into list of keys to avoid extra cases
            self.Table[val] = [key]

        else: #Collision - append
            self.Table[val].append(key)
            col = True
            index = len(self.Table[val]) - 1

        return val, col, index

    def delete(self, key):
        val = self._get_value(key)

        if self.Table[val] == None: #Deleting an unexisting element
            return -1, 0

        elif key in self.Table[val]: #This is the O(n) part of the hashtable
            index = self.Table[val].index(key)
            self.Table[val].remove(key)
            return val, index

        else: # No match was found in list, element does not exist
            return -1, 0

    def lookup(self, key):
        val = self._get_value(key)

        if self.Table[val] == None:
            return -1, 0
        else:
            if key in self.Table[val]:
                index = self.Table[val].index(key)
                return val, index

            # No match was found in list, element does not exist
            return -1, 0

    def clear(self):
        self.__init__()
```

I am using and returning some variables to keep track of collision, values, and indexes to print to the user.

I want to understand how I could improve this implementation - still using only lists (no sets for checking).
From a time complexity perspective or even code design, how can I make this more efficient? What design choices were poorly made in my code? What can I improve in this to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

#### Restructuring and micro-optimization

Hard-coded table size `54` is better defined as class constant:

```
T_SIZE = 54
```

Encapsulate the crucial list/table at least as *protected* property `self._Table`.

Calling `self._get_value(key)` and the condition `if self._Table[val] == None` are repeated in most crucial methods. To reduce that noisy repetition an additional method can be defined which will return a tuple of calculated value `val` and `is_empty` ("empty slot" flag):

```
def _check_value(self, key):
    val = self._get_value(key)
    is_empty = self._Table[val] is None
    return val, is_empty
```

It doesn't make sense to construct `if ... else` conditional if the 1st **`if`** branch **`return`** 's immediately.

Both **`delete`** and **`lookup`** methods, on existing item, will perform **2** access/lookup operations on `self._Table[val]`:

- `key in self._Table[val]`
- `self._Table[val].index(key)`

To reduce access operations there we can apply **`try/except`** *trick* and returning the needed result in each separate block. See the final implementation below:

```
class HashTable:
    T_SIZE = 54

    # Initialize the table with a fixed size
    def __init__(self):
        self._Table = [None] * HashTable.T_SIZE

    def _get_value(self, key):
        total = hash(key)
        return total % HashTable.T_SIZE

    def _check_value(self, key):
        val = self._get_value(key)
        is_empty = self._Table[val] is None
        return val, is_empty

    def insert(self, key):
        val, is_empty = self._check_value(key)
        col = False  # Collision flag
        index = 0

        if is_empty:  # Empty slot - turn into list of keys to avoid extra cases
            self._Table[val] = [key]
        else:
            self._Table[val].append(key)  # Collision - append
            col = True
            index = len(self._Table[val]) - 1

        return val, col, index

    def delete(self, key):
        val, is_empty = self._check_value(key)
        if is_empty:  # Deleting unexisting element
            return -1, 0

        try:
            index = self._Table[val].index(key)
            self._Table[val].remove(key)
            return val, index
        except ValueError:  # No match was found in list, element does not exist
            return -1, 0

    def lookup(self, key):
        val, is_empty = self._check_value(key)
        if is_empty:
            return -1, 0
        try:
            index = self._Table[val].index(key)
            return val, index
        except ValueError:  # No match was found in list, element does not exist
            return -1, 0

    def clear(self):
        self.__init__()
```

In case if `_get_value` method won't be used in standalone context - you may easily inline it into `_check_value` method.

Sample usage:

```
h = HashTable()
h.insert('abc')
h.insert('abc')
print(h.lookup('abc'))
print(h.lookup('1abc'))
print(h.delete('abc'))
print(h.delete('abc'))
print(h.delete('abc'))
```

The output (consecutively):

```
(8, 0)
(-1, 0)
(8, 0)
(8, 0)
(-1, 0)
```